# Auto resizing the JTable column widths

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecolumn

I need my JTable to automatically re-size its column widths to fit the content. I found the [`TableColumnAdjuster`](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/10/table-column-adjuster/) class very useful. But there's a small problem. Say i have 5 columns, and their content is very short. In that case, if i use the auto adjuster, it sets the first four columns widths according to their content and gives all the rest of space to the last column. Please see the example.

[image]

Here the last column, `Balance` is given all the excess space. But what if i need to give that space to one of the middle columns. In the above case, i need to assign that space to the third column, `name`. I tried modifying the `TableColumnAdjuster` class's `adjustColumns()` method. But I couldn't get it working.

I tried both `column.setPreferredWidth()` and `column.setWidth()` for changing column sizes. But seems it doesn't change anything. How can I effectively change the column sizes of a `JTable`. If there's some other alternative or a direct answer to my main problem, that's better. Thanks!

Answer (score 76, accepted):

You can try the next:

```
public void resizeColumnWidth(JTable table) {
    final TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();
    for (int column = 0; column < table.getColumnCount(); column++) {
        int width = 15; // Min width
        for (int row = 0; row < table.getRowCount(); row++) {
            TableCellRenderer renderer = table.getCellRenderer(row, column);
            Component comp = table.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
            width = Math.max(comp.getPreferredSize().width +1 , width);
        }
        if(width > 300)
            width=300;
        columnModel.getColumn(column).setPreferredWidth(width);
    }
}
```

[image: JTable]

*This needs to be executed before the resize method.*
If you have:

```
table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF);
```

[image: JTable]

Comment: This is fantastic, ended up using it.  I added a check before the setPreferredColumnModel call that looks like "if(width > 300)width=300;" which fixes some cases where I'm displaying really long data fields.  I'd suggest adding that to the answer--and you might also extract out min/max width (Would make fantastic optional parameters--in fact I'm going to go do that in my codebase now.)  (I wish I knew when it was cool to edit something like that into someone else's answer...  Since it's not CW I hate to change content without permission.)

Comment: Hi, @BillK Feel free to edit/add the code... and if you have, a screenshot. ;)

Comment: can I also somehow evaluate the header too so that its text won't get cut off?

Comment: @Xerus Add `width = Math.max(width, table.getColumnModel().getColumn(column).getPreferredWidth());` after line 9 in the above code to evaluate the headers.

Comment: Worked perfectly, as expected!

Answer (score 4):

There is no option to automatically resize one column larger than the other.

Maybe you can to something like:

```
tca = new TableColumnAdjuster( table, 0 );
tca.adjustColumns();
TableColumnModel tcm = table.getColumnModel();  
TableColumn tc = tcm.getColumn(1);
tc.setWidth(tc.getWidth() + 25);
```

This would allow you to add extra space to column 1. This extra space would only be added the first time the table is displayed.

Another option is to use:

```
table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
```

This would allocate extra space proportionally to each column.

Comment: This is the opposite of what was asked.
"table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);" resizes all columns evenly without considering the content length.

Answer (score 4):

**setAutoResizeMode()** will tell your table how to resize you should give it a try will all different options available to see the differences, in My case I wanted to specifically resize two columns and let it decide how to adjust all the other ones.

```
jTable1.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_NEXT_COLUMN);
TableColumnModel colModel=jTable1.getColumnModel();
colModel.getColumn(1).setPreferredWidth(25);    
colModel.getColumn(2).setPreferredWidth(400);
```

Answer (score 1):

With a slight modification to [Paul Vargas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17627497/5645656), you can also take into account the column header size:

```
public static void resizeColumnWidth(JTable table) {
    final TableColumnModel columnModel = table.getColumnModel();
    for (int column = 0; column < table.getColumnCount(); column++) {
        // Account for header size
        double width = table.getTableHeader().getHeaderRect(column).getWidth();
        for (int row = 0; row < table.getRowCount(); row++) {
            TableCellRenderer renderer = table.getCellRenderer(row, column);
            Component comp = table.prepareRenderer(renderer, row, column);
            width = Math.max(comp.getPreferredSize().width + 1, width);
        }
        if (width > 300)
            width = 300;
        columnModel.getColumn(column).setPreferredWidth((int) width);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
JPanel jp = new JPanel();
jp.add(table);

jp.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1)); /* little trick ;) and believe me that this step is important to the automatic all columns resize! A import is also needed for using GridLayout*/
table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS); // this is obvius part
```

Answer (score 0):

With a slight modification to [Paul Vargas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73748381/294317), you can also take into account the column header's content:

```
public static void resizeColumnWidth(JTable table)
{
      TableCellRenderer renderer;
      TableColumn column;
      Component component;
      Object header;
      int rowIndex, minWidth, width;

      column = table.
         getColumnModel().
         getColumn(colIndex);

      renderer = table.
         getTableHeader().
         getDefaultRenderer();

      header    = column.getHeaderValue();
      component = renderer.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, header, false, false, -1, colIndex);
      width     = component.getPreferredSize().width;
      minWidth  = Math.max(width, 0);

      for (rowIndex = table.getRowCount(); --rowIndex >= 0; )
      {
         renderer  = table.getCellRenderer(rowIndex, colIndex);
         component = table.prepareRenderer(renderer, rowIndex, colIndex);
         width     = component.getPreferredSize().width;
         minWidth  = Math.max(minWidth, width);
      }

      column.setPreferredWidth(minWidth);
    }
```

Note: This is different from [Cardinal System's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73748381/294317) in that this code takes into account the header's content and Cardinal System's answer just takes into account the header's size.