# Java - JTable can't show title of columns because it is crowded

Tags: java, jtable

I'm new to Java and trying to make a simple program that will display the data inside the database. My problem here is I have 20 columns and I can't see the data or even the column title because it is too crowded. I tried combine it with JScrollPane and still doesn't work.

Here is my code

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import net.proteanit.sql.DbUtils;

public class ManageDatabase extends javax.swing.JFrame {
Connection conn = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
PreparedStatement pst = null;


/**
 * Creates new form ManageDatabase
 */
public ManageDatabase() {
    initComponents();
    conn=javaconnect.ConnectDb();
    Update_table();        
}
private void Update_table(){

    try {
    String sql = "Select * from table_AOD_Pump_Accessories";
    pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    rs=pst.executeQuery();

    Table_AOD_Pump_Accessories.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

    }
    catch(Exception e){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

    }  
}
```

Comment: Show us some code, man!

Comment: I updated it, have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `JScrollPane`  and add the `JTable` in it.

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
```

Try this one also if you want to show the scroll bar as per your requirement.

```
JScrollPane scrollPaneChatHistory = new JScrollPane(table, 
            JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER,
            JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
```

---

--EDIT--

Try

```
table.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
```

For more info have a look at [Auto resizing the JTable column widths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17627431/auto-resizing-the-jtable-column-widths).

Comment: I tried it but I think I did it in a wrong way because it just add a Scroll Pane and I still can't read all the data and columns title.

Comment: Is horizontal scroll bar visible?