# How to set width column AbstractTableModel

Tags: java, swing, abstracttablemodel, jtableheader, column-width

Need help how to set width column in `AbstractTableModel`?? i am set autoRsizeMode=Off in my table properties and i am trying like this `tablePriceList.getColumn(0).setWidth(400);`this code working fine when i am using `DefaultTableModel`  but it does'nt work in `AbstractTableModel`,
and here is my `AbstractTableModel` Class :

```
public class ListPriceTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {
  private final List<ListPrice> price ;
  private final String[] columns ; 

  public ListPriceTableModel(List<ListPrice> ListPrice){
    super();
    price = ListPrice ;
    columns = new String[]{"Nomor","Kode Voicher","Description","Provider", "Nominal", "Sales Price"};
  }
  // Number of column of your table
  @Override
  public int getColumnCount() {
    return columns.length ;
  }
  // Number of row of your table
  public int getRowsCount() {
    return price.size();
  }
  // The object to render in a cell
  @Override
  public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
    ListPrice club = price.get(row);
    switch(col) {
      case 0: return club.getNomor();
      case 1: return club.getKode_voucher();  
      case 2: return club.getDescription();
      case 3: return club.getNominal();
      case 4: return club.getProvider_name();
      case 5: return club.getSales_price();
      default: return null;
    }
  }

  // Optional, the name of your column
  @Override
  public String getColumnName(int col) {
    return columns[col] ;
  }
    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return price.size(); 
    }

}
```

i have google it and still not found any solution.

Comment: Table model has no influence to column width. If you want to get an answer please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @Xstian So what should i do..?i just want to set width the column table

Comment: [SOLVED] i found what i need in here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17627431/auto-resizing-the-jtable-column-widths, thank you all.